# Can we cast a object into a class type whose name is only known?

Tags: java, jsp, reflection

I have to dynamically fetch the tables whose names are available in dropdown in a jsp. Upon the selection of table name corresponding columns should be printed. For that I was running a loop in jsp and trying but is it possible to cast an object of "Object" type into a class whose class name is only known and after that using that object I have to acesss the corresponding class methods.

ex: className I got from jsp is "Book" and I have a class `Book.class` which has a method `getName()` so something like this is what I wanted:

```
 Object obj1 =  Class.forName(className).cast(obj);
 obj1.getName();
```

Here `obj` is the object I have got through session.

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens? :)

Comment: If you don't know the desired type at compile time, what would such a cast achieve?

Comment: I was getting a compile time error stating obj cannot be resolved into a variable.

Comment: `obj1.getName();` will give compilation error.

Comment: @user1283438 And that makes sense, since the type `Object` doesn't have a `getName()` method, and all you told the compiler is that "`obj1` is some kind of `Object`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forName takes a String and you can't call getMethod on Object because there is no such method. Ideally you'd have an interface defining the method that's common in all the types you can select from your drop down.

If that is not an option, then there is an uglier option using reflection where you don't actually need to know the type in advance:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Book");
// Object obj1 = clazz.cast(obj);
// The method getName() is undefined for the type Object

Method m = clazz.getMethod("getName");
String res = (String) m.invoke(obj);
```

I'd not recommend using this code as is in any production application though. You'll need quite a bit of validation and exception handling in order to make this work safely.

Comment: This would solve my problem if the object "clazz" is not newly created rather the object coming through session is utilised i.e there is an "obj" of type Object class being passed along with a string which represents the class name to which it has to be type casted. Is it possible to type cast the "obj" into the string named class (Book, if above example is considered) and call a particular method which requires a string argument, @Dennis Hunziker

Comment: I don't get your point, in the code I posted, the Object named obj is an instance of type Book: `Object obj = new Book("test");`, so that's what'd be in your session with a String representing the type. If you already have an instance of the Class object representing Book then you just leave away the first line.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis Hunziker, the solution you suggested helped me out.

Comment: Thanks, I'd appreciate if you'd [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419), if it solved your problem, by clicking the check-mark and I'm sure others will too.

Comment: Object obj1 = clazz.cast(b); This statement is causing "ClassCastException" in some methods (where b is an input parameter of type Object) at run-time where as it was successful when used as  Object obj1 = clazz.cast(b.get(i)); where List<Object> b is an input parameter to the other method. In both the methods Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("np.com.mshrestha.bookstore.model.Book"); is common

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behaviour. If b has a runtime type of List then trying to cast it into Book is going to throw a ClassCastException, but if the ith element from that list is a Book then getting that casted is fine but assinging it then to Object isn't helping you in any way. I think you're only option is to go with reflection all the way or, as mentioned before, let all your domain classes implement an interface containing that common method you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that but the object must belong to that class or some of its child class else it will give you a ClassCastException. You also need to pass complete path of that class mean fully qualified class name with package.

```
Object obj1 =  Class.forName(com.Book).cast(obj);
obj1.getName();
```

Comment: If obj is of "Object" class the super class of all classes in java then the downcast in this case into Book class is not possible?